# Several Low pass filters generate offset when applied on an embedded system on C++

Tags: python, butterworth, c++

I need to implement a real time butterworth low pass filter on some data, I have an already implemented and tested butterworth function, but when filtering data from one specific variable I get an offset. Removing the filter also removes the offset.

The following image shows the reference data (green) and the filtered data (blue), The action of the filter is weaker than expected and a big offset appears.

[image: Process run]

The following image shows comparison between the filter's input (green) and output (blue), as well as the output provided by the same filter on the same data but running on a python plotting tool (dashed brown). The python filter has been directly translated from the embedded system's code, and uses the same weighting parameter.

[image: offset]

The code for the C++ live low pass butterworth:

```
    float32_t update_butterworth(float32_t measure, bwFilter_t * bwFilter)
{
    if (bwFilter->isInitialised)
    {
        bwFilter->filteredValue = bwFilter->weight * bwFilter->filteredValue +
                                        bwFilter->c_weight * measure +
                                        bwFilter->c_weight * bwFilter->previousMeasure;
    }
    else
    {
        bwFilter->c_weight = (1.f - bwFilter->weight) / 2.f;
        bwFilter->filteredValue = measure;
        bwFilter->isInitialised = pdTRUE;
    }
    bwFilter->previousMeasure = measure;
    return bwFilter->filteredValue;
}
```

The code for the python low pass butterworth:

```
class ButterWorth:

def __init__(self, weighting):
    self.weight = weighting
    self.previous_measure = 0.
    self.c_weight = (1. - weighting) / 2.
    self.filtered_value = 0.

def process(self, measure):
    self.filtered_value = self.weight * self.filtered_value + self.c_weight * measure + \
                          self.c_weight * self.previous_measure
    self.previous_measure = measure
    return self.filtered_value
```

As of now the python implementation acts exactly as expected, while the C++ code doesn't. I have tried other filtering techniques such as regular low pass filter and sliding average, but the offset always appears.

If you notice any errors please let me know, I also apologize in case I didn't format something properly, its my first question and I don't know the site well.

Thank you in advance

Comment: is this a first-order filter?  also, is it fixed-point?  it *appears* to be floating-point, but I cannot tell.

Comment: @Isaac: you you post the class definition header file ? On first glance , the code looks fine. It's definitely a first order filter.

Comment: @Hilmar: yes here it is:

`if filter_name == 'butter': filter = ButterWorth(0.5)`

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: First order yes, and floating point.

Comment: Then, because it's floating point, it shouldn't get stuck in a limit cycle on the decay.

Comment: @Isaac: that's the constructor, not the class definition. One way to debug it, is to send it a unit impulse as a test signal and post what you get. Should be a pure exponential decay

Comment: @Hilmar: Thank you for the advice, if I'm not misunderstanding anything the class definition is already in the code I posted.

Comment: Sorry, I must have overlooked this. Your code looks fine although it's odd that seem `update_butterworth()` seems to duplicate the `process` method. Which one are you using. The code looks fine to me, so you probably need to apply standard debugging methods: use input signals where already know the answer, look for discrepancies and single step to figure out where it goes wrong. Use a unit impulse, delayed unit impulse, two impulse, steady state sine wave, etc. It's possible that problem is not in your filter code but somewhere else. Did you do a unit test on the filter class ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I found out the reason why all of this was happening and will be posting it soon.

Comment: @Isaac will you post the reason/solution?